# How do I download an aspnetForm page with links

Tags: asp.net, .net, wget

I'm trying to download a municipal planning plan together with all the relevant documents.
All documents can be reached from the [following link](http://www.mavat.moin.gov.il/MavatPS/Forms/SV4.aspx?tid=4&et=1&mp_id=ppnCWTcsST9gG0%2fa0ayWnjFyZ%2bo14s221Ujlpi7UvR4jIRAHLKhJ8lOLSkomZ%2fvlHk8b2T0oENpI6Wh2hKzxQJCw9BPJP8gav%2ftgiKlk5S0%3d)

I've tried the following command (that worked well for other sites) and some variations without success.

```sh
wget -E -k -r -l 3 "http://www.mavat.moin.gov.il/MavatPS/Forms/SV4.aspx?tid=4&et=1&mp_id=ppnCWTcsST9gG0%2fa0ayWnjFyZ%2bo14s221Ujlpi7UvR4jIRAHLKhJ8lOLSkomZ%2fvlHk8b2T0oENpI6Wh2hKzxQJCw9BPJP8gav%2ftgiKlk5S0%3d"
```

The same plan in their new site I can't get the files either,
https://mavat.iplan.gov.il/SV4/1/5000931297/310

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, these days, and especially with .net web sites?

We don't use hyper-links with a simple (full) path name to actual files from the web server. In fact in most cases one will not even give the web server rights to those folders. (they are not exposed to Internet Services).

So, no actual links as a full "url" to documents exist.

What happens is  when you click on a button or button link? Then the code behind on the web server runs. (and that is code you don't have). And further more, that code behind can browser, read,  retrieve any file from any folder  on the server or other servers.  But links from the web site don't exist and it not even possible to type in a url to resolve to a actual file name on the server.

So the server side code (not internet services) goes and grabs the document. In fact,  the documents could be in a database. So, the code behind on the server side runs and pulls the binary data from the database (which represents a valid PDF file). Or the code behind reads the file from disk and then STREAMS the file for a download.

Now, this is often done for reasons of security. It means that no valid URL exists to get at a document.

Not only is this done for security, but from a developer point of view, it often better to retrieve a row from a database. That row can have the information you SEE rendered on that form, but the web page is not static, and the display of information is thus a developer coding a pull of rows from a database, and then you simply "assign" that data to some type of control - save datagrid, or listview or whatever. (this assignment of data is only 1 or two lines of code, and then the control + web server renders that datagrid control.

So, this is done since the developer thus only assigns the result of a database query to the control when then renders on the form. Thus, to add or remove documents? Then you only have to edit the database for  the information on the web page to render.

As a result? There is no direct links to the actual documents on the server. To retrieve a document, you would have to send to the web site the exact command required.

You can hit f12 (most browsers support this). This will put your browser into developer mode. If we do this, and then select elements (select element feature). Now click on a pdf link. You get this:

```
<img src="../images/ft/file_PDF.gif" style="cursor:pointer"

onclick="openDoc('99000526871729',
'AABA7BE646E182B67DB1C15220E531DF36BBB591D8EEA7757435B2606C08E6F9')">
```

So, note above. The above code event openDoc is the SERVER side code you have to run to retrive a document. There is thus NO link. And you not going to be able to wire up, or run your OWN  web page that hits that server and runs the routine "onclick".

However, the onclick DOES expose the internal database document numbers used to pull/read and retrieve a given document. But the path name, and how the code gets/grabs this file? You have no idea, and HAVE to run server side code (c#, or vb.net) code. That code as noted grabs the file and then uses code to "stream" the file when you download or click on a link.

So for simple HTML like pages? Well, for those that took a one day HTML course? Sure, such web sites will have scr=some path name to a valid url). And these simple systems thus allow you to enter a URL to grab/get a document. And those documents are fully exposed to the web site, and a simple valid URL path name to a file exists. Not so with asp.net, and as noted, this is not only done for security, but it a better over all developer experience to write code that grabs the files as opposed to rendering full path link names to files.

There are many additional benefits.  For example, the database that drives this likely has a setting (or some settings) that contain the path names to the documents. If they run out of storage, or say want to move older files to a much slower storage system, which of course is much lower cost? Then can move the files, and update the path name columns in the database. The web site will continue to work, since we NEVER using a exposed URL on the web site. And as  noted, actual direct URL's don't exist, and the web server (IIS) as opposed to the code behind will not even have rights to the file names.

As a result?

You not be able to simply pull the web page, and THEN extract the URL's to file names.

What you might be able to do is write code that loads the web page, and then scans all the  event code stubs for the links, and have your code click on each button with web browser automation. But, even that don't allow you to enter file names into the download prompts.

So, what you ask is not easy, likely not possible, and a very difficult task. And the simple reason is that site does not use simple HTML and static links to files, and it never actually exposes a direct link to files, and even worse yet is the web server does not have or even allow a URL direct link to a site - they don't exist, and the web site will not even have rights or even allow such URL's to file names. (only the .net code behind does - not internet services).
and grabs the document and then code "streams" the file to to the web site or link you clicked on. So the simple HTML coders in the past would create say a folder (usually a virtual folder) that points to the files on some server/folder. But with .net, it easier (and far more secure).

Modern development tools don't use old fashioned ideas like a URL's to directly retrieve a file - they are designed differently.

In some cases, URL's are allowed or created, and this is done for reasons of sharing links. So if you have a cute video or document? Then the designers of the system will often permit use of parameters in the URL, so  you can share a link to someone else. This page has no such provisions. So, you can share a link to the page, but no actual URL to documents or even provisions to allow URL's to a document even exists.

So this quite much means to retrieve a document, you have to go to that web page, and ONLY when you click on a document will the web site "stream" down that one particular document in question.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.
Thanks for the detailed reply. It's been a few decades since I designed my own page :)
Are there any new tools that overcome this by emulating a browser and mouse click?
What is the correct technical term (key word) for such a page design?
Thanks

Comment: Search for web scraping tools. Code can create instance of browser and even fire button clicks. However save as dialogs etc. tend to NOT allow code without user intervention. .Browsers don't allow this for reason of security. Browser can't up-load or download files without user intervention. If they could then you visiting my site would allow browser to search and grab files on your computer  such as banking or emails etc.  So non user file operations are limited for security reasons. Full urls can be downloaded  AFTER you pull out the file list  from the browser. But no file links exist here.